# A question about Automotive failsafe IC ATA6842

Tags: dc-motor, automotive, circuit-design

I am a student of Vehicle engineering.
I had read a datasheet of a automotive failsafe IC:[ATA6842](http://pdf.datasheet.su/atmel/ata6842-plqw.pdf) and I don't know what it is.
Please have a look at P4 of the datasheet.

[image]

I know what in the red frame is a low side MOS BDC control circuit and a current differential amplification circuit.

But what I don't know is,what is the use of the circuit in the blue frame?
What happene to the BDC motor with this circus?

[image]

Comment: A failsafe for what? The electric steering or the rear window wiper? What is the circuit supposed to do?  Add information **in the question** rather than in the comments. I think you mean "circuit" - a circus is something else.

Comment: "TCFET" stands for "Test Current FET", can be used to test if MR12 or MR34 and the current test circuitry work, without actually activating the motor.

Comment: @jimmyB Oh,it is what I don't know.Is this design really useful in reality?I think it will raise the cost.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is on the block diagram on the preceding page of the datasheet:

[image]

The linked IC provides several low side drivers (which you've already identified in the red box) in addition to a high side gate driver for driving an external high-side n-ch MOSFET. The capacitors are connected to the pin labelled `BSC` (Bootstrap Capacitor) for the driver's integrated charge pump. `TCFET` (Test Current FET) drives the gate on `MTCFET1` (and on `MTCFET2`, see below:)

[image]

Issuing a command to the IC that turns on `TCFET` drives current from the net labelled `K15` (battery voltage after the ignition switch, via. [DIN 72552](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_72552)) into the current measurement comparator inputs through an external shunt resistor which, as JimmyB points out in the comments, is helpful for testing the functionality of the low-side drivers and/or other external circuitry connected to `TCFET` without activating the motor. The output of the comparator could then be measured by an external A/D to verify proper functionality before an error condition occurs.

The relays `RL1` and `RL2` change the direction of the motor. Driving `RL1` pulls the "top" of the motor to `K30` (the battery voltage, again DIN 72552) and `RL2` pulls the "bottom" to `K30`.

Comment: I know this.But what's the use of RL1 and MTCEFT1?Is this something for BDC motor driving?

Comment: No, MCFET1 cannot "source current to the motor". Look at the circuit more closely.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, don't know how I missed it; thanks for pointing that out - edited the original answer.